# Is there a better way to write this while loop?

Tags: assembly, while-loop, raspberry-pi, arm

I want to create a simple while loop in ARM Assembly written on a raspberry pi running Raspbian.

The C syntax of my while loop is:

```
while (r0 < r1) {
    r0++;
}
printf(r0);
```

Simple enough, but what I'm trying is returning a value when r0 >= r1. I have a solution in mind but I feel like there's a better way of doing it.

What I have currently is:

```
/* while.s */
/* C syntax: while (r0 < r1) */
/* program will return register 0 at the end of the loop (which should be 10) */
.text
.global main
main:
/* use registers 1 and 2 to hold values, compare both r0 and r1, break to 'end' if r0 is greater than or equal to r1 */
        mov r0, #0
        mov r1, #10
        cmp r0, r1
        bge end
while:
/* compare registers 0 and 1, break to 'end' if r0 is greater than or equal to r1, otherwise increment r0 by 1, break back to start of 'while' */
        cmp r0, r1
        bge end
        add r0, r0, #1
        b while
end:
        bx lr
```

This will loop fine, but return 10 instead of 9.

The solution that I've come up with is (without updating comments):

```
/* while.s */
/* C syntax: while (r0 < r1) */
/* program will return register 0 at the end of the loop (which should be 10) */
.text
.global main
main:
/* use registers 1 and 2 to hold values, compare both r0 and r1, break to 'end' if r0 is greater than or equal to r1 */
        mov r0, #0
        mov r1, #10
        sub r2, r1, #1
        cmp r0, r2
        bge end
while:
/* compare registers 0 and 1, break to 'end' if r0 is greater than or equal to r1, otherwise increment r0 by 1, break back to start of 'while' */
        cmp r0, r2
        bge end
        add r0, r0, #1
        b while
end:
        bx lr
```

This will fix my problem but I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this without using a third register.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well first of all, more efficient to put the conditional branch at the bottom, so there's no `b` instruction in the loop, *just* `blt`: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)  You already have a cmp/bge before the loop in case it should run zero times.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you care how many iterations the loop runs, and what range of values `r0` has inside loop iterations?  (So you could just `sub r0, #1` *after* the loop, or `sub r0, r1, #1` to `return r1-1`).   Also, you know your C loop doesn't do what you want, right?  Your first asm implements it exactly, and leaving the loop with `r0 == r1` is correct.  Also, what do you want to happen on corner cases like `r1 = 0`?  Do you want it to wrap to `0xFFFFFFFF`?  Or do you want to keep treating it as signed `-1` and have the loop run zero times?

Comment: What is the point of this loop, and what would you criteria do you consider as "better"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how large your values are going to be, but I don't think it really matters if they are not extremely large and you get thousands of loops. So why don't you stick to a loop similar to your c++ example?